# Why do I have to declare a dependency of a dependency to make my build work?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

I'm currently investigating ways to use Gradle and Artifactory efficiently for my company. I was able to build a few small test programs depending on each other and junit for testing.
One of the things we want to achieve is to have the third party libraries we use on our local Server with Artifactory (so not a mirror from Maven). And this is where some problems came up: junit could not function without hamcrest. So I downloaded it but to make the build work I had to specify that extra dependency:

> testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'

But I did not have to do that when using Maven central, only when dealing with my downloaded artefacts on Artifactory.
Obviously, having to do that for libraries with many dependencies would be a pain.
Has anyone ran into this problem? Is there a way to solve it simply or did I just miss something?

(btw I wrote a test: program1 depends on program2, which depends on program3, I then built program3 and published it to Artifactory, then program2 and finally program1. I only had to declare it's dependency to program2 for the build to work, there was no problem in that case)
I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are mixing something up here. Almost certainly this has nothing to dow with Maven Central vs. Artifactory, just us your little experiment with program1/2/3 suggests.

Instead most likely JUnit is causing the confusion.

JUnit works fine without Hamcrest for most things. Only a few features need Hamcrest, like the `Assert.assertThat` method. If you use those features you need to declare Hamcrest as a dependency.

The story gets more complicated, because JUnit used to include a version of Hamcrest, so when you used an older version you could use even `assertThat` without declaring Hamcrest as a separate dependency.

Comment: You're right. What happened is junit could not work as it's dependencies were not downloaded. So adding the extra just provided feedback for me to know what to download for hamcrest (hamcrest-core needed hamcrest-parent). But now that I have it all downloaded, I removed the line and the build worked fine.  
So downloading what I need along with it's dependencies should solve that. Thanks!